# Translate one field based on the other

Tags: jolt

Let's say the input JSON is:

```
[
  {
    "n-services": {
      "@": {
        "my:operation": "none"
      },
      "n-service": [
        {
          "@ports": [
            {
              "my:operation": "delete"
            },
            null,
            null
          ],
          "ports": [
            3510,
            3500,
            3505
          ],
        }
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Now, I want to transform the 'ports' array based on the '@ports' field. As you can see, the index 0 in '@ports' has an operation of 'delete,' which means I want to remove the corresponding element at the 0th index in the 'ports' array. Therefore, the expected output should be something like this:

"ports" : [ 3500, 3505 ],

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried multiple solutions, but none have proven effective. I am considering a custom modifier as the only viable solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The challenge here was the null values in the @ports which makes it hard to capture or filter in the shift spec since the wildcard * in the shift LHS doesnt account for null values. To resolve this I had to use combination of restructuring at the @ports index level to preserve nulls and then use default spec to replace null with new operation value called "unchanged" and finally add another shift spec to perform the desired action based on the operation type. This will help you handle other operation types if exist.

```
[
  // Reformat the @ports where each equivalent index
  // port is assigned the operation from @port. for
  // port with no operation they will be assigned null
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "n-services": {
          "n-service": {
            "*": { //index at n-service
              "\\@ports": {
                "*": "&.@(2,ports[&])"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
   },
  // Default no operation port (=null) to operation unchanged.
  // default only assign values where the field never
  // existed or its a null therefore the delete operation
  // at index 0 will be preserved as is
  {
    "operation": "default",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "my:operation": "unchanged"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  // Finally restructure based on the operation type where
  // ports assigned delete operations will be ignored ("":"") while
  // ports with unchanged operation will be re added to the ports array
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "my:operation": {
            "delete": {
              "": ""
            },
            "unchanged": {
              "$2": "ports[]"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }


]
```